# Can ORM be extended to get data from legacy components?

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, orm, entity-framework-4.3

Can an ORM (Entity Framework/ NHibernate) be extended where it can accept data from some legacy component. Of course, it should retain its basic functionality i.e. mapping data to/from a persistent database.

EDIT: Any link/ponter would be appreciated!

regards,

Comment: @StefanSteinegger a legacy component is an existing component that is part of the complete system. The production team may not wish to disintegrate that component and wishes to use "as it is" apart from some other DB Operations.

Comment: You want to execute a query by the ORM and get data from that component?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger not necessarily query execution. It would most likely be a method call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about EF, but NHibernate can be extended through either Interceptors, Events or both (see http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#events). If you for instance want to add data to an entity as soon as it is loaded from the database, you can use the OnLoad method of an Interceptor or the OnLoad Event by implementing ILoadEventListener and register that implementation in your NHibernate configuration.